# Regex first occurrence of string search gives NULL output

Tags: python-3.x, regex, text, regex-group

I am new to regex and python, I have to find the first occurrence of a string from a text file. And after finding the first occurrence of the string need to find out the string residing the passed string .I only need the first outcome to store in a variable.

THE TEXT FILE LOOK LIKE THIS:

```
Media Attribute (a): rtpmap:97 AMR/8000

Media Attribute (a): fmtp:97 mode-set=0,2,4,7; mode-change-period=2; mode-change-capability=2; mode-change-neighbor=1; max-re...

Media Attribute (a): rtpmap:100 telephone-event/8000
```

And my required output is to get the "rtpmap:97 AMR/800" as a string from the first occurrence of "Media Attribute (a):".

I performed the below code but throws a null output

```py
import re
with open('codecc.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        codecc_search = re.search(r'Media Attribute (a): (\s+) (\s+)', f.read())
        if (codecc_search):
            codecc = codecc_search.group(1)
            codecc = str(codecc)
            print(f"Codecc={codecc}")
```

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Escape special regex metacharacters. Here, `(` and `)` are special and require escaping. Also, to match any non-whitespace, use `\S`, not `\s`.

Comment: codecc_search = re.search(r'Media Attribute (a): (\S+) (\S+)', f.read())

Comment: updated above comment still NULL outcome

Comment: No, I meant `r'Media Attribute \(a\): (\S+) (\S+)'`, you did not escape the parentheses that are special, see https://regex101.com/r/oe0B15/1

Comment: May be because of the string I passed in re.search

Comment: Yeah, you have an issue with the Python code here, too.

Comment: now it prints only"rtpmap:97"instead of "rtpmap:97 AMR/8000"

Comment: Yes, I see, you also need to fix the number of groups and their boundaries in the pattern. See the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```py
import re
with open('codecc.txt', 'r') as f:
    codecc_search = re.search(r'Media Attribute\s*\(a\):\s*(\S+\s+\S+)', f.read())
    if codecc_search:
        codecc = codecc_search.group(1)
        print(f"Codecc={codecc}")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oe0B15/2). *Regex details*:

- `Media Attribute` - a fixed string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\(a\):` - a `(a):` string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\S+\s+\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespaces, one or more whitespaces and one or more non-whitespaces.

The `f.read()` part reads in the file contents into a single string variable, the `re.search` finds the first match only and the `codecc_search.group(1)` fetches Group 1 value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are always a happy explainer.